Proof style with babel
Long ago I used this solution to Changing style of Proof to make the work proof bold. Over time babel got used and I've just noticed that it has now reverted back to the original style (contrary I believe to what the answer I followed suggested). As egreg pointed out in this comment babel hijacks \proofname, and now I can't get the desired effect. Is there a nice work around so I can use both packages and still achieve the desired solution?
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel} % <- Comment this out and you get the desired formatting. 
\let\oldproofname=\proofname
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\rm\bf{\oldproofname}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
results. \qedhere
\end{proof}
\end{document}


off-topic: you should not use two-letter font switches in latex. and they don't take an argument anyway.

The commands \rm and \bf have been deprecated for about 30 years. Don't use them, ever.
Changing \proofname will definitely fail with babel anyway.
A long standing feature request for amsthm is to add the possibility of choosing a font shape or weight for \proofname. You can do it quite easily.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{xpatch}

%%% modify proof
\providecommand{\proofnamefont}{\itshape}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\normalfont\proofnamefont}{}{}
%%%

%%% \proofname in boldface
\renewcommand{\proofnamefont}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
results.
\end{proof}

\end{document}

Note that \qedhere is generally not necessary. You should use it only if the proof ends with a list or a math display.


I found on this page the following solution which appears to work:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand{\prooffont}{\rm\bf}
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\prooffont}{}{}


Commands \rm and \bf are outdated, I suggest to change \rm\bf to \upshape\bfseries. xpatch is not really needed, babel's command \addto\captionsUKenglish{\renewcommand{\proofname}{\upshape\bfseries Proof}} would work as well.
